# How to use WebStorm JavaScript Debug configuration without Google Chrome?

Tags: debugging, webstorm

I have FF (v.35), Opera (v.12), and IE (v.11) installed on my Win 7 x64 PC and wanted to debug a (locally stored) HTML file that loads a JS script.

After adding the file to a new project, I went to File > Settings > Tools > Web Browsers and unticked the web browsers that I do not have installed.

So those settings now looks like this:

[image: webstorm_web_browsers_settings]

After that I went to "Edit Configurations" and added the HTML file that I wanted to debug, as shown below:

[image: webstorm_edit_configurations]

(note that the HTML file is not empty, even though it is named that way)

Now if I click on the 'Debug (default)' button, I get these messages that Windows has a problem finding chrome and WebStorm is waiting for a connection from the Chrome plugin:

[image: webstorm_error_messages]

On another hand, if I click on the 'Run (default)' button it opens the page in Firefox as expected.

I am either doing something wrong or have something misconfigured.

How can I tell WebStorm not to use Chrome for debugging?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, **JetBrains WebStorm does not support the JavaScript Debug configuration in any browser other than Chrome** (or other Chrome-based browser such as Dartium).

To debug in FireFox versions 33-35 (for WebStorm v.10 this does not work in FF v.36), you have to enable Remote debugging in Firefox and then use the Firefox Remote run configuration, as explained here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13801#comment=27-904044.

Answer (score 0):

ATM run/debug configuration of **"JavaScript Debug"** type only supports Chrome.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14987 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress (currently planned for WebStorm v11).

---

To debug using Firefox you have to use **"Firefox Remote"** type of configuration [instead](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13801#comment=27-904044) (for additional stuff /issues -- see related tickets).